# Is $[0,1]$ a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ in the cocountable topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $\mathbb{R}$ has the topology consisting of sets $A$ such that $\mathbb{R}-A$ is either countable or all of $\mathbb{R}$, is $[0,1]$ a compact subspace?

I've found the example $A_n = [0,1]-\{\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},\cdots\}$ but I don't know how it answers the question. Why this set cannot be covered by finitely many open subspaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $\{A_n\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. If $[0,1]$ is compact, then there exists a finite set $F \subset Z^+$ such that $\{A_n: n\in F\}$ covers  $[0,1]$.
Let $n_0 \in Z^+$ such that $n\le n_0$ for all the $n\in F$ and hence $\frac{1}{n_0} \in [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n\in F}A_n$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks  a  lots @ paul

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of open sets that covers $[0,1]$. It admits no finite subcover.

Comment: thanks    a lots @ Martin